# Disable iPad touch and hold functionality on all but one element

Tags: javascript, ipad, touch, mobile-safari

I would like to be able to disable the iPad touch & hold functionality for everything on my site except for one image. I've managed to do this for all images using the:

event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();

on touchstart & touchmove events, and this works great.  But I haven't been able to work out how to allow this functionality for a particular image on my site.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Helmut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I've worked out a way to do this.  Basically I put a condition around those event statement, like this:

```
if (!saveImage)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

I only did this for those functions called at the touchstart event, as I didn't need to (or want to) prevent defaults for any other touch events.  All I needed to do then was to set the saveImage Boolean appropriately so that it was only true when I was touching the image I wanted to save (which was pretty straight forward).